# OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found... (Python 3.7 & Visual Studios 2017)

Tags: python, visual-studio

When I try to run my code in Visual Studios 2017, I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dsl0017\Desktop\ANOPP2 extraction\hartIITestPy\HartTwoUsingCfd.python.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ANOPP2_api import *
  File "C:\Users\dsl0017\Desktop\ANOPP2 extraction\hartIITestPy\ANOPP2_api.py", line 11, in <module>
    ANOPP2 = CDLL('libANOPP2.dll', RTLD_GLOBAL)
  File "C:\Users\dsl0017\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
Press any key to continue...
```

The relevant code up leading to the error is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np
import sys
import os
from ctypes import*

from ANOPP2_api import *
```

Please help... I've been stuck on this for a week. It's a major roadblock in my research.

Comment: Welcome to SO! So the API expects a DLL to be present on your system. This appears to be part of the official NASA ANOPP2 release. Did you install that on your system?

Comment: I did install it on my computer!

Comment: The error you got seems to indicate that it could not open the DLL (libANOPP2.dll). Maybe it cannot be found because it's not in the search path.

Comment: The file you're referring is in a folder in the search path.. It is in 
C:\Users\dsl0017\Desktop\ANOPP2 extraction\Lib\Windows.x86_64, which is appended to the sys.path list when I print it out

Comment: OK. According to the `ctypes` documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#loading-shared-libraries), Windows error 126 can also be caused by failure to load supporting libraries (DLL). To verify if your main DLL can be found, use `ctypes.find_library('libANOPP2.dll').

Comment: doing this, I get the error 
AttributeError: module 'ctypes' has no attribute 'find_library'

Comment: Wait nvm, I figured it out.. But it returns 'None'

Comment: 'None' means: cannot be found. Also try with 'ANOPP2' as an argument. It is not entirely clear to me what the argument value should be for Windows.

Comment: ANOPP_api.py should not be edited by me. It was distributed with the software to work behind the scenes. It aids the user code by supplying the necessary function definitions and boolean types that are to be used in the user supplied (or provided demo) code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I tried to run the ANOPP2 platform on Pycharm. I shifted to Visual Studio and the error magically went away. I don't know as to the why it happened and why it went away.